# Text color of selected item in SwiftUI Picker

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker, disabled-control

When using a Picker on a Form in SwiftUI, if the Picker is disabled, the selected item's text is light gray. It appears a little too light for readability. How can this be changed? 
[image: Disabled control]

[image: Enabled Control]
There is no font-colour option, especially for disabled state, identified in Apple's documentation.

```
    var strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

    @State private var selectedStrength = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Strength")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< strengths.count) {
                            Text(self.strengths[$0])

                        }
                    }
                    .disabled(true)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Select your cheese")

        }
    }
}
```

I would like to change the font color so that it can be made more readable.

Answer (score -2):

Get the index in that `ForEach` and check it with the `observables.selection`. Then change the color for text if needed:

```
...
ForEach (0 ..< observables.Intact.endIndex, id: \.self) { index in
    Text(self.observables.Intact[$0]).tag($0)
        .foregroundColor(self.observables.selection == index ? .red : .blue )
}
...
```

[image: Picker]

You can combine `selection` && `editMode` if you need to detect it for setting colors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's a couple of important points that you've missed in my question:  
1) The Picker appears in a Form, and 
2) The text color is the color when the Picker is disabled.

Number 1 means that the Picker is not of the wheelPicker style, at least not as the default Picker style of a form.

Number 2 means that the text is not the 'normal' state, that is, the text of a disabled control is lightened. I want to stop that or lessen it. What is causing the lightening? Is it text color, a modifier on a row, how can I change it?

Comment: 1) I used your code to reproduce the situation, please update it if it's different with the real one.  2) as I said, `selection` && `editMode` to modify *disabled* stated.

Comment: Sorry, selection && editMode don't cut it !  You know this is within SwiftUI right?

Comment: You changed the code **A lot!**. So this is a completely different question. I thing you should revert the code back and ask a new question my friend.